# SQL Group by max

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 5.5 and having a problem with a select query. I'm trying to select rows with values between two datetimes in one column, and group by the maximum datetime in another column. The table structure is something like

```
|          Model_Init |          Model_Time | Location_ID | Var_ID | Value |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------| ------ | ----- |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 04:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  76.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 05:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  77.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 06:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  78.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 07:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  79.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 08:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  80.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 06:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  81.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 07:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  82.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 08:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  83.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 09:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  84.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 10:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  85.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 11:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  86.2 |
```

I want to select a continuous group of times between two Model_Time values, ie:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WRF_data_norm 
WHERE Location_ID=123456 AND 
        Var_ID=23 AND 
        Model_Time>='2014-08-23 04:00:00' AND 
        Model_Time<='2014-08-23 10:00:00'
GROUP BY Model_Time;
```

Which might returns results:

```
|          Model_Init |          Model_Time | Location_ID | Var_ID | Value |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------| ------ | ----- |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 04:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  76.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 05:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  77.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 06:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  78.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 07:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  79.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 08:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  80.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 09:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  84.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 10:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  85.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 11:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  86.2 |
```

where I want distinct values of Model_Time with the maximum values of Model_Init, ie:

```
|          Model_Init |          Model_Time | Location_ID | Var_ID | Value |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------| ------ | ----- |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 04:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  76.2 |
| 2014-08-22 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 05:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  77.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 06:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  81.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 07:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  82.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 08:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  83.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 09:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  84.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 10:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  85.2 |
| 2014-08-23 06:00:00 | 2014-08-23 11:00:00 |      123456 |     23 |  86.2 |
```

I'm not sure how to alter the query.

EDIT: Solution found:

`SELECT Max(Model_Init), Model_Time,Location_ID, Var_ID,Value
FROM WRF_data_norm
GROUP BY Model_Time, Location_ID, Var_ID, Value
HAVING Location_ID=123456 AND Var_ID=23 AND Model_Time>='2014-09-23 04:00:00' AND Model_Time<='2014-09-23 11:00:00'
ORDER BY Model_Time;`

Comment: I see no difference between the results you are getting and the ones you want.

Comment: As I also cannot spot the difference, perhaps you are relying on the unreliable `MySQL extension` to `GROUP BY`; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html where the results can be `indeterminate`

Comment: The Model_Init values are different - the group by doesn't select the maximum value of Model_Init for a distinct Model_Time. I probably should have used different example Values, will modify the post.

Comment: `The Model_Init values are different`; no they aren't, the before and after sets are identical - or I need new glasses

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT   Model_Init, Model_Time, Location_ID, Var_ID, MAX(Value)
FROM WRF_data_norm 
WHERE Location_ID=123456 AND 
Var_ID=23 AND 
Model_Time>='2014-08-23 04:00:00' AND 
Model_Time<='2014-08-23 10:00:00'
GROUP BY Model_Init, Model_Time, Location_ID, Var_ID;
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: I got an empty set with this query, however you made me think of something to try which did work:

SELECT Max(Model_Init), Model_Time,Location_ID, Var_ID,Value
FROM WRF_data_norm
GROUP BY Model_Time, Location_ID, Var_ID, Value
HAVING Location_ID=123456 AND Var_ID=23 AND Model_Time>='2014-09-23 04:00:00' AND Model_Time<='2014-09-23 11:00:00'
ORDER BY Model_Time;

Comment: there is no need to use the `HAVING` clause for those filtering conditons, it could be achieved with the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Your Model_Init is the same. So there will be no effect of using max with Model_Init. You need max value of the col Value thats y you have to use max function with the col value.